# Conditional import with top-level-await in Firefox 85

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-modules

I'm trying to do a conditional import (Javascript of ES6 flavour) in a script that I load (or rather, that I would *not* load!) through HTML in Firefox 85.

Here is the script: (`myscript.js`)

```js
let ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE = false;
let require;
if (ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE) {
  const {createRequire} = await import('module');
  require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
}
```

Here is my HTML page: (`example.html`)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="module" src="myscript.js"></script>
    <!-- I also tried with async, but that did not change anything: -->
    <!--script async type="module" src="myscript.js"></script-->

    HELLO

  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I am aware of the flag protecting this feature in Firefox, so I took care of setting `javascript.options.experimental.top_level_await` to `true` in `about:config`.

But I still get the following error in the javascript console upon loading the page:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: top level await is not currently supported`

For information, the same page is loading fine on Chrome 88, provided the proper flag is set too (`#enable-javascript-harmony`).

Why doesn't it work on Firefox 85?
Did I do something wrong?

[Here](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/297) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) I got the confirmation that the development work is already done and shipped with the release 85, and should be enabled with the flag.

Edit:
I just filled [a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1693570). Let's see what the developers say.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on Bugzilla: the feature is actually still in development, and the flag is inactive in the public release.

The flag is enabled only in Nightly builds for now, and the official documentation, which is misleading at the moment I am writing this, will be fixed to clarify that.

See [the bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1693570).